# Returning minimum date from other table as sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a query that returns all open orders and populates a new column with the string 'In List' if there is a specific activity in the associated activity table for this order ID.

How do I have the new column return the min(Activity.ActivityDate) for a specific activity instead of the 'IN LIST' string or if there is no Activity of that particular name then NULL?

This is the query that works, but isn't what I want:

```
SELECT 
  Orders.DateOrder,
  Orders.ID,
  case
    WHEN Orders.ID IN (
        SELECT Activity.IDOrder from Activity 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON (Activity.IDOrder=Orders.ID)
        where Activity.ActivityName IN ('Processed','Packaged'))
    THEN 'IN LIST'
  END as NewColumn  
FROM Orders 
where Orders.EndDate Is Null
```

I tried replacing 'IN LIST' with min(Activity.ActivityDate) but I get a 'could not be bound' error - presumably because it can't identify it in the outer query. But if I add it in the outer query I restrict the results to only those open orderIDs with a specific activity, whereas I need them all even if no activity exists.

The existing query is quite slow to run.

What is a faster way of doing this?

Order Table

| ID | DateOrder | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 | 2023-11-01 |
| 2 | 2023-10-07 | NULL |
| 3 | 2023-12-01 | 2024-01-02 |
| 4 | 2023-12-04 | NULL |
| 5 | 2024-01-18 | NULL |

Activity Table

| ActivityID | ActivityName | ActivityDate | IDOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Processed | 2023-10-02 | 1 |
| 2 | Packaged | 2023-10-31 | 1 |
| 3 | Processed | 2023-10-20 | 2 |
| 4 | Packaged | 2023-10-27 | 2 |
| 5 | Confirmed | 2023-12-04 | 4 |
| 6 | Processed | 2024-01-27 | 5 |

Required results

| DateOrder | ID | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-07 | 2 | 2023-10-20 |
| 2023-12-04 | 4 | NULL |
| 2023-01-18 | 5 | 2024-01-27 |

Comment: First Tag your database system also add `create table` with `Insett into` with data and the result you want to get

Comment: You can skip the LEFT JOIN, it adds no additional Activity.IDOrders to the subquery result.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: @jarlh keep the join, but promote it to be part of the main query. then we can drop the `CASE` expression and subquery completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Orders.ID` is a unique key, or at least the combination of `Orders.ID` and `Orders.DateOrder` will be unique in the table, this should do it, and in less time, too:

```
SELECT 
  o.DateOrder,
  o.ID,
  MIN(a.ActivityDate) NewColumn
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Activity a ON a.IDOrder = o.ID AND a.ActivityName IN ('Processed', 'Packaged')
WHERE o.EndDate IS NULL
GROUP BY o.DateOrder, o.ID
```